# Restful design of GetAll, GetMine, GetForUID

Tags: rest, api

We have a couple of resources that could belong to a particular user. We need to solve 3 use cases:

1. Get all the resources regardless of the ownership
2. Get the resources that belong to me
3. Get all the resources that belong to a particular user

What is the best option to express these endpoints RESTFully?

Comment: `GET /resources[?owner=...]`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure its the *best option* but *one* option is:

1. Get all the resources regardless of the ownership:
   `GET /api/v0/resources`
2. Get the resources that belong to me
   `GET /api/v0/users/me/resources`
3. Get all the resources that belong to a particular user
   `GET /api/v0/users/<uid>/resources`

Note that `me` is a supposedly special `uid` in this context. You could merge options 2 and 3 under option 3 if you can replace `/users/me/` with `/users/<id of me>/`

Answer (score 0):

This is a subjective opinion, but this is how how I would handle this:

```
/resource <- all resources
/resource/123 <- a specific resource
/user/1234/resource
```

'my' resources don't need a special case, but sometimes we do create a separate endpoint to *find* the current user:

```
/current-user <- might be a 302 redirect to /user/####
```